# Crystal report Dynamic parameter problem

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I set parameter using SetParameterValue() method in code behind page.

But the problem is when I click on any of the option e.g. export button,

It prompt me Parameter values. It does not reuse parameter values, yet I am not refreshing report.

so is there any thing that I'm missing?

Comment: Any subreports? Any data coming from stored procedures without default parameters?

Comment: Which version of Crystal are you using? Also, if you can provide the section of code where you are loading the parameters there may be something glaring that someone can see.

Comment: I don't now exactly which version is this but it comes with VS 2008. And I use button click event to set parameter because the same page is also used for asking parameters. if still you want to see code then let me know I'll put it.

Comment: I have the same issue. did you solve your problem?

Comment: @Elham Not yet, Said bye bye to Asp.net!

Answer (score 0):

In which page event are you loading the report? I've had this problem before when loading the report in page_load. I resolved it by loading in page_init.

I'm gonna dig up some code to double check on that. I haven't used Crystal with ASP in a long time.

Comment: I load reort on Page_init() event but the same problem I have.